# How do I temporarily disable video output on PotPlayer?

Tags: audio, video, media-player, daum-pot-player

I'm using PotPlayer in workplace. It is allowed for people to listen to an audio file in the background here, but I think it may cause a problem if they see me watching video. Is there a way of temporarily disabling the video on PotPlayer so that the audio will go on playing while the screen is black? I'm looking for a tweak in the settings or a keyboard short cut.

Note: Don't suggest me extracting audio data from the video files to a standalone disk file, since I will turning on the video occasionally.

Comment: Why not minimize the window?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I don't want people around to see the video when I restore the window to change the playing position. And also, I need to pause it when someone comes to me to tell me something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click and go to Video, Video Renderer, select **Null Video Renderer (Compressed)**. This kept the audio playing, but the video output turned black.

You can set up your own hotkey.
[image: Hotkey]

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: @hkBattousai There isn't a keyboard shortcut shown. Easy way I found is press the context menu key (which simulates right click), press V (it goes to Video), Video Renderer is the first option so press the right arrow to open the menu, tap the up arrow twice and press Enter. It becomes fast if you get used to it. You can set up your own hotkey in the Potplayer settings.

Comment: There is a hot-key ( ` ) to minimize/restore window size and this will turn video on/off keeping control on the screen. Checked on version 1.7.2